# Button event not stopping

Tags: asp.net, dojo, postback

I am using DOJO (1.7) together with ASP.NET. I have attached an onclick event to the submit button but am trying to validate on client side first. In plain javascript, if I used a 'return false' statement, that stopped the postback. However, returning false in the code does not stop the statement while using DOJO. I am a DOJO newbie and have no idea what to do. Thank you for your time.

```
require(["dojo/io/script", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (script, on, dom) {
        on(dom.byId("<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>"), "click", function () {
            dom.byId("<%= txtSellPercentage.ClientID %>").value = "farax";

            return false;

        }
            )
    });
```

Comment: Can we see the mark-up that is generated when the application is run?

Comment: require(["dojo/io/script", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (script, on, dom) {
        on(dom.byId("abc_btnSubmit"), "click", function () {
            dom.byId("abc_txtSellPercentage").value = "farax";

            return false;

        }
            )
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to tweak the code a little. Apparently I was trying to call some event method without importing the particular script for events. So here goes

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    require(["dojo/io/script", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/_base/event"],
    function (script, on, dom, event) {
        on(dom.byId("<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>"), "click", function (e) {

            dom.byId("<%= txtSellPercentage.ClientID %>").value = "farax";
            event.stop(e);


        }
            )
    });

</script>
```